# Click event triggers multiple file windows to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

whenever I press a file upload button on my page it triggers all file upload buttons which exist on the page, each button has the same class so I tried to apply the $(this) selector to restrict the response to one file upload window.

HTML

```
        <div id="sectionInfo">
            <div id="sectionWrap">
                <div id="sectionInner">
                    <label class="inst head">Section 1</label>
                    <input class="textOver" type="text" name="sectionTitle1" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" placeholder="Section Title" onfocus="this.select();">
                    <label class="inst ib">Please enter any text you would like associated with the section.</label>
                    <textarea style="margin-top: 3px" name="sectionContent1" value="<?php echo $body; ?>" onfocus="this.select();" placeholder="Section Description"></textarea>
                    <label class="inst ib">Please upload the image associated with this section, .PNG required.</label>
                    <input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="sectionImg1" class="upload" />
                    <input type="button" id="fileStyle" class="fSOver fileStyle" value="Upload Section Image!" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There are multiple instantiations of this block, the site admin is able to dynamically append infinite nodes to the page via some javascipt, this is where my problem lies. From a usability perspective it is a total nuissance if one button click opens 30 windows consecutively for your 30 sections.

My current JS looks like this

```
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click", '.fileStyle', function(){
           $('.upload').click();
        });
    });
```

How would I go about prompting the file upload dialog for the targeted button only?

Comment: `$('.upload').click()` is targetting everything with class `upload`. Give them unique IDs and have them target the appropriate individual one.

Comment: $(this).prev().click(); or $(this).prevAll('.upload').click(); will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on("click", '.fileStyle', function()
    {
        $(this).siblings('.upload').click();
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on("click", '.fileStyle', function()
    {
        $(this).prev().click();
    });
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot. Im new to JS so picking things up a long the way :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Keep up learning man! jQuery is pretty cool/powerful... :)